# Helps on CUDA programming guide

Tags: cuda

My confusion is about one statement made in appendix C.3 in CUDA programming guide. The statement is that "
To guarantee co-residency of the thread blocks on the GPU, the number of blocks launched needs to be carefully considered. For example, a block per SM can be launched as follows:"

```
cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);
// initialize, then launch
cudaLaunchCooperativeKernel((void*)my_kernel, deviceProp.multiProcessorCount, numThreads, args);
```

I understand that this piece of code schedules `deviceProp.multiProcessCount` thread blocks on a device and the size of each thread block is numThreads. I could not understand why the above code snippet will guarantee that there will be one thread block scheduled on each SM and exclude the case that multiple thread blocks are scheduled to some SMs and the rest SMs are idle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't guarantee that.  What it does guarantee is that the blocks will all be resident/scheduled on a SM.  In either case that you describe (all threadblocks assigned/scheduled to unique SMs, or all threadblocks assigned/scheduled to unique SMs except 2 which are assigned/scheduled on the same SM), all threadblocks will be *resident* i.e. scheduled on a SM with their warps possible to be scheduled by a SM warp scheduler.

This is the requirement for co-residency to make cooperative grid launch work.  It is not required that every threadblock be scheduled to a unique SM.  It is only required that every threadblock be scheduled, i.e. unpacked on a SM so that its warps are selectable/schedulable by a SM warp scheduler.

Why does the 1 threadblock per SM heuristic guarantee co-residency of all blocks?  Because the contrary case would be all but 1 of the blocks scheduled, with (at least) 1 SM remaining absolutely "empty".  The block scheduler guarantees that such a condition would not persist indefinitely.  Eventually the block scheduler will not allow the last remaining block to be unscheduled, but will assign it to an "empty" SM (or another SM for discussion of the pathological case you point out that is not ruled out by CUDA block scheduling rules).  With no loss of generality, we can also extend this 1-threadblock-unscheduled argument to be 2 or more threadblocks unscheduled, with a corresponding number of empty SMs on the machine, with no loss of validity/correctness in this argument (i.e., the block scheduler would not allow those conditions to persist, either).

Also note, while not directly related to this question, that the cooperative grid launch mechanism rules out concurrent kernels for correctness.  The cooperatively launched grid must be allowed to solely occupy the machine, for correctness.

As a final note, the 1-threadblock-per-SM heuristic is simple, easy to understand, and easy  to code for.  It is also correct for the above stated reasons (it guarantees co-residency of blocks).  However it is not necessarily *optimal*.  The programming guide as well as the CUDA CG sample codes demonstrate use of the occupancy API to derive optimality (i.e. maximal number of threadblocks to launch, while still guaranteeng co-residency).

Comment: Thank you, Robert, for explaining this to me. Now I understand it.